Why does my Word VBA macro fail to make specific function words (e.g., 'max') in equations non-italic?
I asked ChatGPT to write a Microsoft Word 2019 macro to italicize all math inside the document. but some function words like "max" or "sin" must be regular. it gave me this code:
Sub FormatMathEquations_Correct()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim eq As OMath
    Dim functionsList As Variant
    Dim functionWord As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim termRange As Range

    ' List of math functions to remain regular
    functionsList = Array("max", "min", "lim", "sin", "cos", "tan", "log", "ln", "exp")

    ' Determine the range to process
    If Selection.Type <> wdSelectionNormal Then
        ' No selection, process the entire document
        Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    Else
        ' Process only the selected range
        Set rng = Selection.Range
    End If

    ' Loop through all math zones in the range
    For Each eq In rng.OMaths
        ' Italicize the entire equation first
        eq.Range.Font.Italic = True

        ' Loop through each term in the equation
        For Each termRange In eq.Range.Words
            For i = LBound(functionsList) To UBound(functionsList)
                functionWord = functionsList(i)
                ' Check if the term matches one of the function names
                If Trim(termRange.Text) = functionWord Then
                    ' Set the function to regular (non-italic) font
                    termRange.Font.Italic = False
                    termRange.Font.ItalicBi = False
                End If
            Next i
        Next termRange
    Next eq

    MsgBox "Math equations formatted successfully!", vbInformation
End Sub

but it does not make words like "max" in equation regular. it italicizes everything and ChatGPT could not fix it. What is the problem? And how can I fix it?
I tried to search for the word "max" but it is not found in equations. Maybe that's the problem.

I don't think that eq.range contains any words. It only contains an oMath object.

Your ChatGPT code will never work, for the simple reason that the expressions it's trying to find are written as ASCII text but the equations use Unicode text. The unreliability of ChatGPT code is why its use here is banned.
